# Remove firebase completely from an app

Tags: java, android, firebase

Few months ago I created an app with firebase in it but recently my firebase account got hacked. So I wanted to know if there is any way I can remove the firebase from my app completely.

P.S. I'm still learning

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to check your gradle file, manifest file mainly. Along with that any other file that you might have used firebase in. One way is to goto the firebase docs and check how you add firebase to an app and just unfollow those steps, same for adding any of firebases modules.

You can press `Shift` twice to do a project wide search for the keywords `Firebase` although in my personal experience it's not very reliable.

Easiest way would be to delete any compile statements related to `Firebase` in the `app.gradle` file as well as the `project.gradle` file ( you need to be looking out for a google file in here [ check firebase docs for more info ] ) related to firebase and run the app, android studio will throw a bunch of errors if you have remnant code, then it's  just a matter of going to the locations that caused the errors and removing those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new Firebase account.
And change the google-services.json file in your project.
You will have to download this new file from your new account.

Otherwise(if you dont want to use firebase any further),

You need to remove the dependencies in the gradle file, and all the code related to firebase and re-release your app.

You just cannot change the firebase configuration remotely after release! 
You need to release your app again!

Comment: Please don't use uppercase. People usually will think you are shouting to them.